# Excel Pivot Creating MDX instead of DAX against Tabular Cube

Tags: sql-server, excel, mdx, dax, ssas-tabular

I have deployed a tabular SSAS database using Visual Studio to the server. I am now trying to connect Excel with this database using a pivot table ("PivotTable Report"). This all works fine however it seems to run extremely slow.

Interestingly I decided to profile the SSAS tabular database on the SQL Server so I could see what sort of query the Excel pivot table was generating. To my shock it was creating some horribly complex and inefficient MDX statement. This is very strange as I thought DAX should be generated against SSAS tabular by default?

[image]

After doing a bit of searching around, it seemed like the "Power View Report" that can be created through Excel could be another option. After building the report and running it, performance was very fast. Profiling the server again I found that DAX was being generated instead of MDX which is what I was originally expecting.

[image]

The question now is can I change a connection string or setting somewhere so that I can use the standard Excel "PivotTable Report" as shown below with a SSAS tabular database that generates an efficient DAX query as opposed to an inefficient MDX query?

[image]

Comment: When you "browse" a cube, always an MDX is generated in the background. Whereas PowerPivot issues DAX to query data. That's the way it is. So, sorry. You need to deal with it, mate.

Comment: Yes this is very annoying as the user experience is really bad when it takes about 30 secs to update a pivot table. The Power View Report runs in like 1 to 2 secs but has some limitations compared to the standard PivotTable Report. Interestingly if I handcraft the MDX and run through SSMS it takes about 2 secs too!

Comment: Yep the default MDX is quite ugly. Unfortunately there is no way to control it.